# Roblox Time Trials timer is broken

Tags: scripting, game-development, roblox, luau

I'm a small developer on Roblox and I need help for my new game, "G4LC's Time Trials". The timer is fine for the first 0.2 seconds but the it just goes berserk. Essentially, when I walk into a part that starts the timer, it does begin the timer, but suddenly about 9 extra numbers appear, all I want is for the timer  lay-out to be like "0:00", [here's the link](https://youtu.be/MedqAbEE6kw) to the video of the problem.

I put the timer in, I tested, it ended out like that

There is no other problems, except, it's probably in the TimerGUI. The TimerGUI is what counts and counts and counts. Here's the code:

```
local PlayerGui = 
game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")

local Timer = PlayerGui:WaitForChild("TimerGui").Frame.Timer
local BoolVal = 
game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("BoolStartEnd")
local Time = 0

while wait(0) do
if BoolVal.Value == true then
    Timer.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    Timer.Visible = true
    Timer.Text = Time.."s"
    wait(0.1)
    Time = Time + 0.1
elseif BoolVal.Value == false then
    Timer.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)
    Time = 0
    end
 end
```

Comment: I will edit the post with the code.

Comment: Done, here's the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the timer goes crazy like that is because your `Time` variable is stored as a floating point decimal number. They are notorious for things like this

```lua
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000001
--And
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.29999999999999
```

An easy way to ignore this behavior is to format your the number when you display it.

So try something like this :

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local PlayerGui = Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")

local Timer = PlayerGui.TimerGui.Frame.Timer
local BoolVal = Players.LocalPlayer.BoolStartEnd

local Time = 0.0 -- seconds

local function updateTimer(deltaTime)
    Time += deltaTime

    -- format the time to be in milliseconds 
    Timer.Text = string.format("%.2f ms", Time * 1000)
end

local timerConnection
BoolVal.Changed:Connect(function(isTrue)
    if isTrue then
        -- update the color 
        Timer.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
        Timer.Visible = true

        -- start the timer!
        timerConnection = RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(updateTimer)
 
    else
        -- update the color
        Timer.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)

        -- reset and stop the timer
        Time = 0
        if timerConnection then
            timerConnection:Disconnect()
            timerConnection = nil
        end
    end
end)
```

Rather than use an infinite while-loop, I'm using the more Roblox-appropriate `RunService.Heartbeat` signal. It fires every time the game engine updates the world, and the `deltaTime` argument is the number of seconds that have passed since the last update. This way, the timer doesn't have to waste time checking if the `BoolVal` is true; if the `BoolVal` is true, it will start the timer, otherwise it will stop the timer entirely.

Comment: is it possible to format as 0:00? (Also thank you)

Comment: Sure, I updated the string.format call

Comment: When I said "is it possible to format as 0:00?" I meant ) 0:00ms, sorry about that, like the las time but snip of the minuets. (Actually it's fine) Thank you so much

Comment: It would be very nice, thank you, I know you help a lot of other people, so if you can't just spend more time on this, that's fine, thank you!